# Failed to start script in Nodejs Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemon

I was using Nodemon.js. For production i decided to delete nodemon and set script "start" to "node index.js" but now i am encountering this error. ( I have completely uninstalled nodemon from my system, deleted from dependencies, re-installed node.)

Already tried Npm cache clean --force, 
Uninstalled Node multiple times

```
> hpgrmnode@1.0.0 start E:\Abhi\hpgrmnode
> node index.js

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js
npm ERR! file E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js
npm ERR! path E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! hpgrmnode@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! spawn E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hpgrmnode@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mukesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-02T16_31_24_429Z-debug.log
```

This is log file
https://pastebin.com/EAiKbBii

**Note**
I have recently changed my folder name from hpgrm_node to hpgrmnode but still the path is showing for hpgrm_node
*** npm ERR! file E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js
npm ERR! path E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

---

**Dependencies**

```
{
  "name": "hpgrmnode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "HPGRM web application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "Abhishek",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "alert": "^5.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "edge.js": "^1.1.4",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-edge": "^2.0.2",
    "express-fileupload": "^1.1.7-alpha.3",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.22.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.16"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.16.1"
  }
}
```

With simple command "> node index.js"
Getting this warning

```
    E:\Abhi\hpgrmnode>node index.js
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    The system cannot find the path specified.
```

And if i am trying to install nodemon
getting this error

```
E:\Abhi\hpgrmnode>npm install nodemon --save-dev

> nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall E:\Abhi\hpgrmnode\node_modules\nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.1.2 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})
npm WARN hpgrmnode@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js
npm ERR! file E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js
npm ERR! path E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall: `node bin/postinstall || exit 0`
npm ERR! spawn E:\Abhi\hpgrm_Node\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nodemon@2.0.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mukesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-02T16_49_22_968Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Delete `node_modules` folder and do `npm install` again. After that run application using `npm run start`

Comment: Same result. It is looking for nodemon.